"Clear" Button Function not Triggering in Simple Calculator App
I'm building a simple calculator app using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I’ve encountered an issue where the "Clear" button in my calculator does not seem to trigger the associated function.
Issue:
The displayAppend function works correctly when the calculator buttons are clicked, but the clear function is not getting triggered when the "C" button is clicked. I have confirmed that the console.log statement inside the clear function is not appearing in the console.
Here are the files I’m working with:


let disp = document.querySelector("#display");

function displayAppend(a) {
  disp.value += a;
}

function clear() {
  console.log("hi");
  disp.value = "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <input id="display" readonly>
    <div id="key-container">
      <button onclick="displayAppend('+')" class="keys orange">+</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('7')" class="keys">7</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('8')" class="keys">8</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('9')" class="keys">9</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('-')" class="keys orange">-</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('4')" class="keys">4</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('5')" class="keys">5</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('6')" class="keys">6</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('*')" class="keys orange">*</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('1')" class="keys">1</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('2')" class="keys">2</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('3')" class="keys">3</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('/')" class="keys orange">/</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('0')" class="keys">0</button>
      <button onclick="displayAppend('.')" class="keys">.</button>
      <button onclick="Calculate()" class="keys">=</button>
      <button onclick="clear()" class="keys orange">C</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="calc.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



I have:

verified that the 'calc.js' file is correctly linked and loaded.
checked that the clear function is correctly defined in the JavaScript file.
made sure the onclick attribute in the HTML button is properly set.

Then, why is the clear function isn't being called or if there's something I might have missed?

There's a built-in function named clear(), you're calling that instead of your function. Give it a different name.

Rename the clear() function to clearDisplay() or something else. I'm not 100% sure why this happens, but I think it's because the clear() function already exists in a browser environment, and it is getting confused.

documentation. It's an obsolete function that doesn't do anything.
